# Using strtol() to Parse Long Values out of Lines of a File

Tags: c, parsing, strtol

When I use `strtol` function to parse long values out of such lines of a file,

```
ffffffff8105b4a5 t send_signal
```

it just returns `ffffffff` instead of `ffffffff8105b4a5`!!!

Here's the code:

```
 uint64_t value1;
 uint64_t value2;
 char *temp = (char *) malloc(100);
fgets(temp,512, fp);
strncpy(line1,temp,16);
value1 = strtol(line1,NULL,16);
printf("str_hex1 = %x\n",value1);
printf("str_hex2 = %x\n",value2);
```

Comment: Your code contains a buffer overflow vulnerability: `temp = malloc(100); fgets(temp, 512, …);` Consider using `fscanf(fp, "%llx", &value1)` instead. This will also help parsing the rest of the line(s).

Comment: @David Foerster: You should make that an answer. That is the best I've seen thus far, though mentioning `<inttypes.h>` macros like SCNu64 might be beneficial since `uint64_t` is already in the code. :-)

Comment: `line1` is **not** a _string_ as it lacks a _null character_ leading to UB in `strtol(line1,NULL,16);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made an answer from my comment following Chrono's suggestion:

### Buffer overflow vulnerability

If you allocate 100 bytes as I/O buffer, you should tell that to the function filling it:

```
char *temp = malloc(100);
fgets(temp, 100, fp);
```

or if you discard that buffer before returning:

```
char temp[100];
fgets(temp, sizeof(temp), fp);
```

### Unnecessary copy

Why not simply

```
strtol(temp, NULL, 16);
```

### Use [`fscanf(3)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) and format strings to parse streams

To parse lines like

```
ffffffff8105b4a5 t send_signal
```

I would write something similar to

```
#include <inttypes.h>

int rv;
uint64_t col1;
char col2;
char col3[64];

rv = fscanf(fp, "%"SCNx64" %c %63s", &col1, &col2, col3);
if (rv != 3) {
    /* error treatment */
}
```

This is a lot more concise than a series of `fgets`, `strtoul` and `strcpy`. It also saves a few memory copy operations, because it operates directly on the `FILE*` buffer.

Furthermore, for situations as with `col3`, GNU (and upcoming POSIX.1) `*scanf` has a conversion format extension `"%ms"` that allocates the necessary buffer for strings so you don't have to (and don't run into buffer overflows). Remember calling `free()` on that though.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that you have a configuration where `sizeof(long) == 4` (i.e. 32-bit `long`). You might want to look into `strtoull()`/`strtoll()` instead of `strtoul()`/`strtol()`, and use `[unsigned] long long` variables instead...

Edit: actually, never mind the `[unsigned] long long` bit, as you already have `uint64_t`...

Answer (score -1):

It seems that `strtol` is out of range (0xffffffff or greater is ULONG_MAX according to [limits.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/) and the [definition](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) of `strtol`).
Although the passed value (8105b4a5) is smaller than 0xffffffff it is bigger than LONG_MAX (system dependent), which is somehow the biggest number `strtol` can deal with.

Due to the fact that you are using unsigned longs the function `strtoul` (see [definition](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoul/)) might be the more appropriate candidate.

To ensure that it is because of this range problem, please check your local limit.h.

Hope that works.

*Jost

Comment: ULONG_MAX is not the same on all systems; `0xffffffff` is the *minimum* value it can have, but it must be the largest value that can fit in a `unsigned long`. In an environment where `long` is a 64-bit type, `ULONG_MAX` will be `0xffffffffffffffff`.

Comment: @rici Yes you are right the limits differ depending which system you are on - and yes I have somehow overseen that it also can be greater. Thats why i link the origin of my information. Thanks for your hint.